# converting decimal into fractions, java and python gives different output

Tags: java, python-3.x, fractions

i'm trying to convert decimals into fractions. my program works just fine for other numbers. however when trying to find the numerator and denominator for 1.0923059908040425e-33,

java gives 1/9
where as python gives 0.

this is my code for java:

```
class Rational {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     println(getDenominator(convertDecimalToFraction(1.0923059908040425e-33)));
}

public static int getNumerator(String fraction) {
    return Integer.valueOf(fraction.substring(0, fraction.indexOf(".")));
}
public static int getDenominator(String fraction) {
    fraction = fraction.substring(fraction.indexOf("/") + 1);
    return Integer.valueOf(fraction.substring(0, fraction.indexOf(".")));
}

static private String convertDecimalToFraction(double x){
    if (x < 0){
        return "-" + convertDecimalToFraction(-x);
    }
    double tolerance = 1.0E-6;
    double h1=1; double h2=0;
    double k1=0; double k2=1;
    double b = x;
    do {
        double a = Math.floor(b);
        double aux = h1; h1 = a*h1+h2; h2 = aux;
        aux = k1; k1 = a*k1+k2; k2 = aux;
        b = 1/(b-a);
    } while (Math.abs(x-h1/k1) > x*tolerance);

    return h1+"/"+k1;
}
}
```

and this is python:

```
print(fractions.Fraction(1.0923059908040425e-33).limit_denominator())
```

i think there's problem in my java code because i'm expecting 0 as correct output, but there is built-in library available for Fractions, and i don't want to use any third-party libraries.

java code works on mostly all inputs. only problem with this one input. please point me error if any.
i would really appreciate if you can provide me with a method or logic that can solve this problem

---

print(fractions.Fraction(1.0923059908040425e-33)) gives 6385627976105849/5846006549323611672814739330865132078623730171904

after adding limit_denominator, it becomes 0. 
i don't know what is going on here..

Comment: Is this a number that python would consider as zero when used here?

Comment: no, 0 is the output.

Comment: Yes. That would make sense if the decimal format used by python for this method was unsuitable for such a small number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a bit a debugging would immediately show what happens. `convertDecimalToFraction` returns `"1.0/9.15494383825455E32"` which is not stupid, but `getDenominator` just ignores the `E32`. You should mimic the `limit_denominator` from Python and say that if `x<tolerance` then the returned value shall be `"0./1."`:

```
static private String convertDecimalToFraction(double x){
    if (x < 0){
        return "-" + convertDecimalToFraction(-x);
    }
    double tolerance = 1.0E-6;
    if (x < tolerance) {
        return "0./1.";
    }
    double h1=1; double h2=0;
    double k1=0; double k2=1;
    double b = x;
    do {
        double a = Math.floor(b);
        double aux = h1; h1 = a*h1+h2; h2 = aux;
        aux = k1; k1 = a*k1+k2; k2 = aux;
        b = 1/(b-a);
    } while (Math.abs(x-h1/k1) > x*tolerance);

    return h1+"/"+k1;
}
```